# How to control space between rows in a matrix that has fraction elements

Tags: matrices, vertical-spacing

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{\theta} 
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 
cos(\theta)cos(\delta) \\ sin(\theta) cos(\delta) \\ \dfrac{sin(\delta)}{l} 
\end{bmatrix} v_f
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical space between the second and the third row is smaller than the first and second row. Any idea how to get the same vertical gap/space between all the rows of this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}


\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}     \\[1.5ex]  
\dot{y}     \\[1.5ex]     
\dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} 
=  
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)\cos(\delta) \\[1ex]   
\sin(\theta)\cos(\delta) \\[1ex]   
\mfrac{\sin(\delta)}{l}
\end{bmatrix} v_f
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cellspace` package for that: you can define minimal vertical paddings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). For the matrix environments, load the package with option `[math]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)\cos(\delta) \\ \sin(\theta) \cos(\delta) \\ \dfrac{\sin(\delta)}{l}
\end{bmatrix} v_f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Renewing `arraystretch` is the standard way to do this, you can make the spacing bigger by providing a factor larger than the `1.5` you have chosen.  However, in your case it would be preferable to use an inline fraction.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{x} \\
    \dot{y} \\
    \dot{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta)\cos(\delta) \\
    \sin(\theta) \cos(\delta) \\
    \sin(\delta)/\ell
  \end{bmatrix} v_f
\end{equation}

Without \verb+arraystretch+
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} \\
    \frac{3}{4}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

With \verb+arraystretch+
\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} \\
    \frac{3}{4}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note you should write `\sin` instead of `sin` etc., and for variables `\ell` is preferable to `l`.

Comment: I don't think that `\ell` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray` you can set row separators and row height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{amatrix}{+b}{
    \begin{+bmatrix}[
        rowsep=0pt,
        rows={ht=7ex},
        column{1}={leftsep=1pt},
        column{Z}={rightsep=1pt}
        ]
        #1
    \end{+bmatrix}%
}{}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{amatrix}
            \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{\theta} 
        \end{amatrix} =  \begin{amatrix} 
            cos(\theta)cos(\delta) \\ sin(\theta) cos(\delta) \\ \dfrac{sin(\delta)}{l} 
        \end{amatrix} v_f
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use phantoms, but in my opinion this calls for the slashed form of the matrix:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{x} \\
  \dot{y} \vphantom{\dfrac{\sin(\delta)}{l}}\\
  \dot{\theta} \vphantom{\dfrac{\sin(\delta)}{l}}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta)\cos(\delta) \\
  \sin(\theta) \cos(\delta) \vphantom{\dfrac{\sin(\delta)}{l}} \\
  \dfrac{\sin(\delta)}{l} 
\end{bmatrix}
v_f
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{x} \\
  \addlinespace
  \dot{y} \\
  \addlinespace
  \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta)\cos(\delta) \\
  \addlinespace
  \sin(\theta) \cos(\delta) \\
  \addlinespace
  \sin(\delta)/l 
\end{bmatrix}
v_f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Remember to use `\sin` and `\cos`, rather than `sin` and `cos`.

[image]